# Is this crab apple branch doomed?

Tags: fruit-trees, tree-care, damage

The leafed branches that are at the end of this larger branch look fine, but I am concerned that the damaged bark has allowed the layer underneath to die. Did anything need to be done for this?

I am getting errors trying to upload a photo from my phone. It used to work fine.

[image]

Comment: try using a different web browser to log in and upload the photo's   :-)

Comment: there's a 2MB size limit - possibly change the photo resolution/size setting for you phone cameral

Comment: 2 MB? That's ridiculous

Comment: 2MB is a pretty big photo file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not to worry. The tree has or soon will compartmentalize the damage (CODIT). Over time new wood and bark will grow in from the sides and it may eventually close completely. Of course, the more foliage there is above the wound, the faster this process will proceed.

When bark is damaged exposing the xylem (wood) there are some cambium cells or xylem initials left on the surface. If covered immediately with polyethylene (e.g., HDPE wrap, visqueen), silicone film, or any other film which is a moisture barrier that transmits oxygen, the tissues will regenerate quickly from those residual cells. But after a day or two they will be dead and covering the wound will no longer accomplish anything productive.

So, I suggest you leave it be and do not reduce the foliage on that stem.

Comment: The wood underneath looks split with some insect holes. Bark chips off easily around the wound. The wood also looks weathered. Still good expectations?

Comment: 'Insect holes' doesn't sound good - you may need help from an arborist for that, especially if you see any sawdust around. Otherwise your tree is exhibiting normal response to the wounding. The cambium desiccated before it could form a callus. As it regrows it lifts the bark around the edges which will easily flake off, as you've noticed. If you gently lift it back you will find the callus 'lip' which has a smooth brown appearance. Normally rough bark will develop over the coming years.The 'weathering' is also normal.